# unable to print parameters from url

Tags: javascript, python, django, request

I'm trying to read 4 parameters from a js request into a django app. This is how I'm doing the js request:

```
site = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/loginfo/" + account + "?userId=" + userId + "&sessionId=" + sessionId + "&url=" + url; 
httpGet(site);
```

This is the url in urls.py:

```
url(r'^loginfo/(?P<siteid>[0-9])/(?P<userdid>)/(?P<sessionid>)/(?P<url>)/$', 'log_info', name='log_info'),
```

And this is the view in views.py:

```
def log_info(request,siteid,userdid,sessionid,url):
print  'siteid' + str(siteid)
print 'userid ' + str(userid)
print 'sessionid ' + str(sessionid)
print 'url ' + str(url)
return render_to_response("products/all.html", locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

But, I'm nothing is being printed on terminal, what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the url pattern in `url.py` doesn't match the url you entered.

You can use the [`request.GET` dictionary](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict) directly to read the query parameters.

For this change url pattern as

```
url(r'^loginfo/(?P<siteid>[0-9]+)', 'log_info', name='log_info'),
```

- `^loginfo/(?P<siteid>[0-9]+)` matches`loginfo` followed by any number of digits.

This ensures that if url has `loginfo/1234`  it will be redirected to `log_info`, with `1234` as the `siteid`

Now change the view as

```
def log_info(request,siteid):
    print  'siteid' + str( siteid )

    # Changes made here.

    print 'userid ' + request.GET[userId]
    print 'sessionid ' + request.GET[sessionId]
    print 'url ' + request.GET[url]
    return render_to_response("products/all.html", locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```